# Zuul prefix when more than a single /path

Tags: netflix-zuul

I have a service with this path `http://myhost.com/v2/1234/brand/order/issues/123` that needs to send the actual call to `http://anotherhost.com/issues/123`.

If I want to avoid the solution to write a `ZuulFilter`

Is there a way, with the configuration to say: the prefix is `/v2/*/*/order/issues` and just use `123`?

```
zuul:
  routes:
    test2:
      path: /v2/*/*/orders/issues/**
      url: http://anotherhost.com/issues/
      stripPrefix: true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no way to configure such behaviour. You need to create custom `ZuulFilter`

By default Zuul will only strip prefixes that do not contain special characters. e.g.

```
zuul:
  routes:
    test1:
      path: /orders/**   <--- '/orders' is stripped
      url: http://anotherhost.com/issues/
    test2:
      path: /*/orders/**   <--- nothing is stripped
      url: http://anotherhost.com/issues/
```